# Problem in opening the model in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo

I started working on Ros. I am using noetic and Ubuntu 20.04. I created a model in gazebo, a simple 4 wheel cart, in gazebo model editor. I added keyboard controls to control the motion of the bot. I created a workspace, made packages and added the required `.sdf`, `.yaml`, `.config`, `.launch`, `.world` and `.py` files and used catkin build and sourced the files.

When I used `roslaunch fourwheelbot model.launch` (`fourwheelbot` - name of the package, `model.launch` - launch file), it displays a different model, some pre-built model present in the gazebo library. I can't figure out the problem. I have been trying this for the whole day.

[image: Photo of the model that is being evoked].

This is the photo of the model that is being evoked when I launch the model I created. I sourced the files properly too.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple duplicate paths in the sidebar.  To help diagnose, make sure that you have only one path to your model.  Gazebo will attempt to load in the order of the resource paths, so if you have a different version, then it may prefer that.